# Is there a way to use regexp match for characters with tilde?

Tags: ruby, regex, unicode, case-insensitive

Look at this:

```
"nAo".match(/(nao)/i) # => #<MatchData "nAo" 1:"nAo">

"nÃo".match(/(não)/i) # => nil
```

is there a way to fix that?

Edit:
It seems that ruby lacks support for unicode characters on regexp comparisons with i flag(ignore case)...
Using MRI 1.8.7p249

Comment: Check your assumption in the question and update it accordingly. From the above it is apparent that Ruby doesn't recognize Ã and ã as being related by case, nothing more. Which, while still an issue, is a different one.

Comment: Perl certainly can apply case insensitivity to Unicode.  It doesn't do NFD-style canonical equivalence by default, but `chr(0x17F) =~ /s/i`, for example, where 017F is the LATIN SMALL LETTER LONG S. Similarly, `"N\N{U+C3}O" =~ /n\N{U+E3}o/i`. To deal with alternate representations with combining marks, you’ll need to convert both the pattern and the string to NFD (canonically decomposed) first.

Comment: I'm not familiar with unicode issues, but it'd be a good idea to mention which version of Ruby you're using.

Comment: @tchrist, did you mean "Perl" or "Ruby"? This is a Ruby question after all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't know about Ruby but most regex engine don't understand uppercase/lowercase for non ASCII characters. The best you can do is:

```
/(n[ãÃ]o)/
```

The problem with understanding uppercase/lowercase relationship is that it is language dependent. Unicode encodes only the form of the character, not the meaning. Therefore an uppercase character in unicode can have different lowercase characters depending on the language.

Take for example `SS`. In English the lowercase would be `ss` but in German it can be `ß`. Another example is the letter `I` which in English has the lowercase `i` but in Turkish its lowercase is `ı` (without a dot). That's because `i` in Turkish has the uppercase `İ` (with a dot).

Due to this, most regex implementations simply give up and refuse to understand uppercase/lowercase relationships for characters outside standard ASCII.

Comment: The problem extends beyond upper-case vs. lower-case. Unicode characters can be defined a couple different ways and still return the same visual representation of a character. See [Ready-made versus composite characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode#Ready-made_versus_composite_characters). Basically, we're not in Kansas any more. :-)

Comment: I certainly wouldn’t claim that most regex engines can’t do Unicode case!  Perl always does, and Java does if you use `(?iu)`.  In Perl, `"\N{U+DF}" =~ /ss/i` returns 1.  Similarly, so does ` "\x{FB03}" =~ /ffi/i`.

Comment: I actually found it too complex to convert patterns and strings to NFD and therefore decided to stick with this simple workaround proposed by slebetman, a little tweaked: string.upcase.match(/NÃO|NAO/) - it seems to be working like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Try to find some [unicode normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence#Normalization) modules for Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Note that Ruby has a better character support since 1.9 (it seems like you run Ruby 1.8.7). The old regex engine was replaced with Oniguruma in Ruby 1.9.

http://www.geocities.jp/kosako3/oniguruma/